# UK visa interview documents

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork

I went to my first ever interview in May 2017 and was granted a 6-month standard visitor visa for the UK, expiring in November 2017. I visited the UK from June to July 2017. I applied again last week, March 2018, and at the interview I was told I did not need provide all the documents prepared and they were not even copied or kept just looked at by TLS interviewer.

Is this positive or neutral? The status on tracking says Application sent to UK visa for decision.

Comment: They're not supposed to not take your documents. You might've gotten duped.

Comment: Thanks Greatone but a year back they took all the documents we had, payslips, bank statements, letter of invite, proof of residence, etc. They put them in an envelope that they sealed in front of us with our passports in a smaller envelope inside that one as well. All  was returned when we received our visa back approved in passport, so naturally we assumed the same would happen now

Comment: the same was supposed to happen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No one except the ECO can tell, wait for their word.